# Does Mitigate Suffering prevent further ability damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

From Complete Champion p 61:

> You can temporarily relieve ability damage.
>   **Prerequisite**: Ability to cast 2nd-level spells.
>   **Benefit**:  As long as you have any restoration spell or another 
>   conjuration (healing) spell that cures ability damage available 
>   to cast, you can confer temporary ability points on yourself or 
>   an ally. As a standard action, you can create 2 points + 1 point 
>   per level of the highest-level such spell you have available 
>   to cast.
>   These ability points can be applied to any single damaged 
>   ability, raising it to a maximum of its starting score. Temporary ability points granted 
>   in this way disappear after 10 
>   minutes, returning the subject to its previous damaged state 
>   unless some other effect restores the lost ability points first. 
>   You can use this effect on the same individual as many times 
>   as you wish.
>   As a secondary benefit, you gain a +1 competence bonus 
>   to your caster level when casting conjuration (healing) 
>   spells.

Are these temporary ability points "lost first" like temporary hp? Can you effectively use this to prevent further damage to that ability by repeated use of this feat? My instincts say no but I can't find a definitive answer anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There's no RAW on this that I can find**

Which I realize is every kind of unhelpful, but I thought I'd make this clear: at no point did anyone actually bother defining what "temporary ability score" *actually means*.

**With that in mind...**

The spell goes through all the fuss and bother to not make it an ability score *bonus*, which it could have very easily done and had the same net effect. This leads me to suggest that a "temporary ability score point" should be treated like a temporary hit point - which is to say, it's lost first before "real" ability score points are. Again, though, *this is not supported by any explicitly written rules*, and is instead my *personal* interpretation based on a potential implication in the wording of the spell and the *extremely* loose precedent of temporary hit points.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that Mitigate Suffering is literally the only place in the entire set of published rules where the concept of temporary ability score points is ever mentioned.